# Any image segmentaion algorithm recommendation?

Tags: image, image-processing, image-segmentation

Hi guys I am currently working on a medical project which requires image segmentation on the figure shown here, which is a tissue image. According to the grey-scale value of the tissue (pixel) we need to assign them different material properties. For now, I am using a pretty naive way of doing this: just classify the pixels within a certain grey-scale range into some kind of material. As you can imagine, here because of the noise and other imperfection of the image, this is not precise enough. I know there are a lot of algorithms on this kind of problem, like before deciding each pixel check their neighbors but I am kind of new to this image segmentation part. Any algorithm recommendation would be much appreciated! Also because this image segmentation is not my main focus, I would rather not spend too much time writing my own code if there is possibly already something out there.

[image]

Comment: You've got serious JPEG compression artifacts in there. I hope this is related to uploading the image here, and you are working with images that have not gone through JPEG compression.

Comment: I think so, the original image format was .tif

Comment: TIFF files can have JPEG compression.

Comment: "... we need to assign them different material properties." I think this part should be much more clear. Either you should define what you mean by material properties or give sufficiently many examples so that the concept of material properties becomes more clear in this context.

Answer (score 0):

As a toy model, given the highly structured nature of your image, I would explore just combining thresholding with morphology operations (and finding the connected components) before moving on to more sophisticated approaches.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Yep I also think finding the connected components might be useful. Do you know is there any mature built-in functions or so on this?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the multigrid technique for image segmentation. it is by far the most efficient and parallelizable algorithm there is for segmentation of images that have well-defined structures like urs.